# Should I define a column type from actual length or nth power of 2(Sql Server )?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2014, sqlperformance

**Should I define a column type from actual length to nth power of 2?**

> The first case, I have a table column store no more than 7 charactors,
>   will I use NVARCHAR(8)? since there maybe implicit convert inside Sql
>   server, allocate 8 space and truncate automatic(heard some where).

*If not, NCHAR(7)/NCHAR(8), which should be(assume the fixed length is 7)*

*Any performance differ on about this 2 cases?*

Comment: use nvarchar(7) to store up to 7 characters. what you heard was incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the actual length of the string.  Now, if you know that the value will *always be exactly* 7 characters, then use `CHAR(7)` rather than `VARCHAR(7)`.

The reason you see powers-of-2 is for columns that have an indeterminate length -- a name or description that may not be fixed.  In most databases, you need to put in some maximum length for the `varchar()`.  For historical reasons, powers-of-2 get used for such things, because of the binary nature of the underlying CPUs.

Although I almost always use powers-of-2 in these situations, I can think of no real performance differences.  There is one. . . in some databases the actual length of a `varchar(255)` is stored using 1 byte whereas a `varchar(256)` uses 2 bytes.  That is a pretty minor difference -- even when multiplied over millions of rows.